# How to trigger lazy loading function before user reaches scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent?

Tags: flutter, dart, lazy-loading, scrollcontroller

The result I want to achieve, is to trigger a lazy loading function before user reaches scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, so in that way I will "minimize" the waiting time in the eyes of user.

In my case, I want the lazy loading function to trigger every time users scroll an 80% of the screen

Here is my working code snippet with lazy loading function triggered when user reaches the end of the screen (classic way):

```
scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        print('bottomReached');        
        // lazy load function 
        }
    });
```

I tried to change the if statement to this:

```
scrollController.position.pixels >= scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent*0.8
```

but it didn't work as expected. What else can I do ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a delta limit, which checks if the scroll is about to read max extent.

```
scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels > scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent*0.8) {
        print('bottomReaching');        
        // lazy load function 
        }
    });
```

Here it checks if the current pixel is more than the delta value (maxExtent * 0.8) and if `true`, loads the function.

One more thing to note is that if in delta range, the function will be triggered with change of every pixel. So it is suggested to have a `bool` variable outside of `scrollController.addListener` to check if the function is already running.

For reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXJboDdIpEA

Happy coding!